# Definition of "epidemic" when using SIR models

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I haven't studied differential equations for a long time, but I have just started looking at material on the SIR model of epidemics.  My problem is that the resources that I've looked at haven't given a formal definition of epidemic.  A couple of the resources seem to use the following definition (although it's not explicitly stated): Let I(t) denote the infecteds function.  Then the disease is an epidemic if there exists a time t such that I'(t)=0.  Is this the technical definition of epidemic? Or there is a another definition?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "definition" is necessary to reconcile the deterministic theory with stochastic counterpart. So, yes, you can take it as a technical definition of an epidemic. Probably better to use an equivalent one: if $I'(t)|_{t=t_0}>0$ then there is an epidemic. But to actually get to the heart of it, start reading about the stochastic models of epidemics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  To be honest, the only reason I'm studying these is so that I can spend two days on them with some ODE students (I haven't thought about ODEs since I was an undergrad, so a lot of the material is foreign to me).  Is there a good intuitive explanation for why this definition makes sense that doesn't involve talking about stochastic models?

Comment: @Dan I do not know a good explanation to motivate definition for the deterministic models. Epidemics is when not negligible part of the population get infected. In the stochastic models there is always a chance that those who infected do not infect others by simply chance. There is no such thing in ODEs.